# Run command once and filter output in multiple files

Tags: grep, io-redirection

Is there anyway to redirect filtered output to multiple files by running mycommand.sh only once?

Example output should be similar to this:

```
mycommand.sh | grep --line-buffered -B 1 A >> file1 ; my command.sh | grep --line-buffered -A 1 B >> file2
```

Or maybe with egrep somehow...

Answer (score 3):

With **`awk`** command:

```
mycommand.sh | awk '/A/{ print > "file1" }/B/{ print > "file2" }'
```

- `/A/{ print > "file1" }` - if a record matches the pattern `A` print/redirect the whole record into `file1`

Comment: Hi, I actually use grep --line-buffered since the script generates output during runtime. Also i need before and after in grep. I updated my command to be similar with what i need. Can i do the same with awk?

Comment: I know.. this should be the last version :)

Comment: No, the files are not being written (that's because of line-buffered needed). However are created by have 0 bytes.

Comment: I just found that i can use unbuffer from packet expect or stdbuf before running mycommand.sh and then awk it. (https://superuser.com/questions/742238/piping-tail-f-into-awk).

Comment: BTW, it's not terribly difficult to implement a simple version of grep-like context printing (`-A`, `-B`, and `-C`) in awk or other languages.  You just need to store the last N lines that you read in (and print them along with the matching line for -B) or read & print the next N lines following a match (for -A).  For `-C`, store & print N/2 lines before, and print N/2 lines after the match.  Print the `--` group separators too if you want.  You can use an array to store the lines - add new lines onto the end, and delete old lines from the start of the array.

Answer (score 3):

`awk` is a better tool for this because it's much faster, doesn't need to fork `grep` or whatever multiple times, and easily scales up to writing to any number files.  Ditto for most other scripting languages, like `perl` or `python`.

In shell, you can use `tee` and [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution).  e.g.

```
mycommand.sh |
  tee >(grep --line-buffered -A 1 B >> file2) |
  grep --line-buffered -B 1 A >> file1
```

(extra line feeds and indentation added to improve readability.  works all on one line if you prefer it ugly and unreadable)

`tee` writes its input to **both** stdout (e.g. to the terminal, redirected to a file, or piped to the next command in the pipleline) **AND** to a file specified on the command line.

In this case, that "file" is a file descriptor provided by process substitution (e.g. another `grep` command with redirected output, as in the example above).

`tee` can write to multiple output files (or process substitution file-descriptors) simultaneously.  For example:

```
mycommand.sh |
  tee >(grep --line-buffered -A 1 B >> file2) \
    >(grep --line-buffered -A 1 C >> file3) \
    >(grep --line-buffered -A 1 D >> file4) |
  grep --line-buffered -B 1 A >> file1
```

---

This works, but I'd personally use something like @RomanPerekhrest's `awk` answer.

Comment: The question is “How do I run a command once ***and use its output as input to multiple programs?***”, not “How do I run a command once *and search for multiple strings in it?*” — that’s just the *example*  — so I believe that this is really the better answer to the question.